# How to submit an unsolicited resume?

Tags: resume, applications

I'm looking around for jobs - particularly one for  linux administrator positions. I've never worked professionally with linux, so I'm looking for a junior/entry level position.

That being said, in searching, many that I'm finding are for senior level positions. These are companies that I'd like to work for, but aren't hiring for my level.

I want to submit a resume anyway. However, finding these jobs on, say, Monster or LinkedIn they don't have a general purpose contact email/phone number. So if I am to submit my resume it has to be to the original job. What kinds of things should I say in my CV with my resume if I'm going to submit in this fashion? Should I just avoid submitting in that fashion altogether?

Comment: If they aren't hiring at your level, and they make submitting an unsolicited resume difficult, I feel like that's a sign that you should move on to another position.

Comment: Thank you for bringing your question here.  This is very similar to one that's already been asked, so I've marked it as a duplicate.  If you feel that it being a non-senior position is a significant difference, please let me know and we can reopen (comment or flag), but in the meantime I wanted to (a) point folks at existing answers and (b) prevent two different piles of answers to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't submit your resume for a job you are clearly unqualified for. Instead, wait for one that you are qualified for.

Finding a job you really want is all about the waiting. If you look today and there isn't a job that you want, then wait for it. Linux administrators are in high-demand, so you will eventually see that Junior position show up. Don't get frustrated.

While you wait for that perfect job to arrive, its a great idea to continue learning more about Linux.  The web (including StackOverflow) have great resources to help increase your knowledge.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: To be clear "Don't submit your resume for a job you are clearly unqualified for. Instead, wait for one that you are qualified for."